# AngularFire - Adding user info to the database after signing in with popup

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I was wondering is there any way to store a user info only when he calls `$scope.authObj.$signInWithPopup('google');` for the first time ( only once per user ).

Currently every time when "user" clicks on the button to get signed in, his data is stored to the database.

I've tried something like this:

```
$scope.googleSignIn = function(){
        $scope.authObj.$signInWithPopup("google").then(function(data){

            $scope.authObj.$onAuthStateChanged(function(user){

                for(var prop in firebasedb.users){
                    if(firebasedb.users[prop].id === data.uid){
                        console.log('same')
                        break;
                    } else {
                        firebasedb.users.$add({
                            name: 'Default Name',
                            id: user.uid
                        });
                    }
                }
            }); // End auth state change
        });// End sign in
    };// End googleSignIn
```

This current code prevents adding new user because it is obvious that id's are the same.

I hope I explained it properly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is that `firebasedb.users`?

Comment: I have a factory that returns firebasedb object and users are firebase database reference

Comment: Try checking your condition with `if(firebasedb.users[prop].id === user.uid)` instead of `if(firebasedb.users[prop].id === data.uid)`

Comment: Same thing, it is the same ID..

Comment: Its happening because you are trying to add the user in a wrong way. `$signInWithPopup` returns a promise which is resolved or rejected when the authentication attempt is completed. If successful, the promise will be fulfilled with an object containing authentication data about the signed-in user. If unsuccessful, the promise will be rejected with an Error object. What you are trying here is adding already authenticated user. So that's what what giving you the `same` on console.